# How to clear socket io whiteboard

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am using the socket io whiteboard (https://socket.io/demos/whiteboard/) in my application. I wish to add a "clear board" option which erases the board for everyone.
I tried implementing it but it only clears for the current user and not for everyone

```js
const clearWhiteboard = () => { 
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
}
```

The code for the whiteboard is exactly as the one given [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples/whiteboard)

I would like the code for implementing this function, Thanks

Comment: The data must come from somewhere.. Just clear the data and redraw the board

Comment: emit an event on the socket and have clients respond to it by clearing the canvas context. e.g. `socket.emit('clear')` and `socket.on('clear', clearWhiteboard);`